# Apache ScriptAlias and access error?

Tags: git, apache-2.4

First of all after much pain i figured out how to make it work in Apache 2.4 windowz. Here is my configuration that seems to work successfully for git clone and push and everything.

**Problem**
**First of all my configuration works.**
There is a  "Require all denied" at / directory. I want only git functionality and nothing else.

***Example Request from a git client***

> 192.168.100.252 - - [07/Oct/2012:04:44:51 +0300] "GET /git/simple/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 264`

***Error caused by that Request***

> [Sun Oct 07 04:44:51.903334 2012] [authz_core:error] [pid 6988:tid
>   956] [client 192.168.100.252:13493] AH01630: client denied by server
>   configuration: C:/git-server/web/simple

There isnt any error at gitclient everything works fine but i get this at error log. Is there any solution for this error to not appear?I worry about log size.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot  "C:\git-server\web"
    ServerName git.****censored****
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT c:/git-server/repositories
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
    ScriptAlias /git/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"


    <LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        Options +ExecCGI
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName intranet
        AuthUserFile "C:/git-server/config/users"
        Require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>
    <Directory />
        Options All
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Options All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```